# How does pagination work in iOS ? (Swift)

Tags: ios, swift, pagination, uicollectionview

I am trying to implement a pagination in a demo app. I am using a UICollectionView to display a lot of images from an API using SDWebImage(Swift). And the API supports pagination like this:

```
"pagination":{  
  "total":355,
  "totalPages":10,
  "page":1,
  "nextPage":2,
  "nextPageUrl":"http://api..................?page=2" }
```

So, how can I do this? Any advice or exsample code? Please help! I am new at Swift :)

Answer (score 0):

You can use the *delegate* method, for the *auto Pagination*:

```
func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, willDisplay cell: UICollectionViewCell, forItemAt indexPath: IndexPath){
    //Load your data and reload them, when the indexPath isEqual to the indexPath of last object  
}
```

***Or***, you can also enable it within  the `cellForItemAt`

```
func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell{
    //Load your data and reload them, when the indexPath isEqual to the indexPath of last object
}
```

Comment: You are getting the page numbers from your API, so you can use them to show, by assigning a section's footer to show the page no. you receive inside "pagination"

Comment: You need to use pageViewController, and while clicking on  the page numbers you may reload your collectionView @SwiftyIso

Answer (score 0):

keep page index for next service your page is pageNumber

```
var page = 0

func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell{
    print("page Num:\(page)")
}

func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, willDisplay cell: UICollectionViewCell, forItemAt indexPath: IndexPath){
     if arrImagesData.count-1 == indexPath.row && arrImagesData.count%10 == 0{
        getMoreImages(page)
     }
}

func getMoreImages(page:Int){ 
   //hit api
   if api_success == true {
       if self.page == 0 {
          self.arrImagesData.removeAll()
       }
   self.arrImagesData.appendContentsOf(api_data)
   self.collectionImages.reloadData()
   self.page = self.page + 1
   }
}
```

Comment: i know but i want to do like this  [link](http://labs.daemon.com.au/uploads/default/49/2ffdd9d0dea1eef3.png) 
under the my collection view

Comment: You need to call the getMoreImages(selectIndex) with the selectedIndex.